# close the customized dropdown in angular 2

Tags: angular

I made a customized dropdown as a component in angular 2
My problem is that if the list of items is opened and you click outside the dropdown area then it should be closed. I tried with (focusout), but there is one issue i am facing. Issue is: If i click on the dropdown the list will be opened (list is designed as ul and li in html) and when i do click on any of the item, as this is out of focus my list will be closed but failing to get the item index where i clicked. Please help me in this. Pretty much stuck there and need some idea to deal with this issue.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't share your code.

Comment: I Agree, a plunkr showing the issue would be ideal.

Comment: I am sharing a small snippet for the same:

<div class = "parent" (focusout) = "closeList()">
  <div class = "text-box">
     <input type = "text" (click) = "openList()"> </input>
  </div>
  <div class = "list-items" *ngIf = "listOpened">
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor = "let item of items; let i = index"  (click) = "selectedItem(i)"> {{item}}</li>
  </ul>
<div>

Comment: so when i click on the item, as this is focus out before the click event list hides ( you can notice by method names, hide and show) and i am not able to select the index of the selected item in the list